# Streaming a flask response that relies on an API call

Tags: python, stream, response

I have two applications, a flask api (backend) and a frontend app. Recently I have had to implement a streaming mechanism so the frontend can call the api to retrieve some data (paginated) and stream its contents back.

I followed the guide described here on how to stream back a Response in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/).

My pseudo-code in the frontend essentially looks like this:

```
 return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

Within `generate()` I do the following:

```
def generate():
    # make blocking api call 
    data = requests.get(url)
    for x in data:
        yield x
```

I am finding that the results produced are inconsistent. My gut feeling is that it's something to do with the blocking API call. Is it okay to have a blocking api call within a generator that is streamed back to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're dealing with the library `requests` you should probably pass in `stream=True` and use that generator in the response. `flask.Response` can either take a string *or* iterable.

```
@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
    _resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    _resp.raise_for_status()

    resp = Response(
        response=stream_with_context(_resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*10)),
        status=200,
        content_type=_resp.headers["Content-Type"],
        direct_passthrough=False)
    return resp
```

Note that the `Content-Type` is also transparently proxied.

To answer your question, it doesn't matter if you use a blocking call in your generator - but I don't see why you would want to do that, given your example.